# Problem with semisimple ring theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

> *Proposition*: For a ring $R$ the following statements are equivalent:
>
> (a) $R$ has a simple left generator;
>
> (b) $R$ is simple left artinian;
>
> (c) For some simple $_RT, _RR \cong T^{(n)}$ for some $n$;
>
> (d) $R$ is simple and $_RR$ is semisimple.

[image]

*My try to understand above proof:*

$(a) \Longleftrightarrow (c)$: OK

$(a) \Longrightarrow (d)$: Please explain why $_RT$ is faithful. If i understand it, clearly $I \leq l_R(R/L)=l_R(T)=0$

$(d) \Longrightarrow (b)$: Since $_RR$ is semisimple and finite generate so $_RR= \oplus_{i=1} ^n T_i, T_i$ is simple. So, $_RR$ has composition series of length n:

$0=T_0\leq T_1\leq T_1\oplus T_2 \leq ... \leq \oplus_{i=1} ^n T_i =  _RR$

Then $R$ is simple left artinian.

$(b) \Longrightarrow (a)$

- First: If $R$ is left artinian, then $R$ has a minimal non-zero left ideal $T$: OK.
- Please explain: $Tr_R(T) \neq 0$

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(a)\implies (d)$ Generators have to be faithful. There exists $I$ and a surjection of $R$ modules $\oplus_I T\twoheadrightarrow R$. What would be a consequence if $T$ wasn't faithful?

$(d)\implies (b)$ No question?

$(b)\implies (a)$ The trace of $T$ in $R$ is the largest submodule of $R$ generated by $T$. You just got done saying that there is a copy of $T$ in $R$, so the trace of $T$ in $R$ is certainly larger than *that*...

Comment: (a)⟹(d): What's ↠, and $\oplus_I T\twoheadrightarrow R$ or $\oplus_I {_R}T \twoheadrightarrow _RR?$, (d)⟹(b): is that right?. Thanks

Comment: Dear @Rachel  sorry for the unexplained notation :) It means a module homomorphism *onto*. I omitted the $_R$ from the $T$, but yes, that's what I meant is the direct sum of copies of $_RT$ as an $R$ module.

Comment: I think that $\oplus _I T\twoheadrightarrow R$ is epic, since generator definition. If $T$ wasn't faithful then $\exists a\in R, a\neq 0: ax=0,\forall x\in M$, so plz tell me the contradiction? Thanks so much!

Comment: OMG, so stupid, I confuse to homological algebra. Sure, $f: \oplus _I T\rightarrow R$ is surjection. So $aR=a(f(\oplus _I(T)))=f(\oplus_I (aT))=0$. Since $a \neq 0$ then $R=0$. It's wrong. Right?

Comment: @Rachel epi=surjection in the category of modules :)  So you agree that aT={0}. What is a(⊕I(T))=? What do you know about annihilators of isomorphic modules?

Comment: @Rachel Right, annihilating $T$ would allow you to annihilate $R$, which isn't possible :)